# Copy URL for local links in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

This is a cross-post from stackoverflow.  It hasn't been moved to superuser yet.  It is related to the question [Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

I'm on an airgapped network. I've been able to install chrome from a generic repository, but getting approval for extensions may take awhile.

In the interim, is there a workaround that would at least let me copy the file URL? R-click opens the same menu as if I'd R-clicked the page instead of the link. No combination of meta keys and clicking (left, middle, right) does anything including copying something to the clipboard.

For reference, this is a linux environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you would like to manually download [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) and install it on an airgapped computer?

I can simply right-click the "install" button for the extension and then download it using "Save link as".

Then, you can follow [this manual](http://techdows.com/2010/10/how-to-install-chrome-extensions-manually.html) on how to manually install the extension.

Basically, you need to rename the downloaded extension from *.crx to *.zip, unpack it and then add it to Chrome by going to the extensions page, switching to the "Developer Mode" and loading it using "Load unpacked extension". The link above explains that procedure step by step using a couple of screenshots.

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  I have to get authorization to copy it to the airgapped network, which could potentially take months.  I was hoping for a manual workaround like what can be done in Firefox.  Also, it doesn't open the PDF in the browser; it tries to 'download' it (which makes no sense, since it's already on a local file share), after which I need to open it in another application.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but it's looking like no other better answer exists.